# SUM UP two columns and then find the find MAX value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sum, max

I am working with Microsoft SQL Server and want to find `E_ID` and `E_Name` where `T1+T2` has the `MAX` value.

I have two steps to reach the necessary result:

1. Find the sum of two columns AS "total" in a table
2. Find the row that contains the maximum value from total

Table named "table1" looks like the following (T2 may contains NULL values):

| E_ID | E_Name | T1 | T2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alice | 55 | 50 |
| 2 | Morgan | 60 | 40 |
| 3 | John | 65 |  |
| 4 | Monica | 30 | 10 |
| 5 | Jessica | 25 |  |
| 6 | Smith | 20 | 5 |

Here is what I've tried:

```
SELECT 
    E_ID, E_Name, MAX(total) AS max_t
FROM 
    (SELECT  
         E_ID, E_Name, ISNULL(T1, 0) + ISNULL(T2, 0) AS total
     FROM    
         table1) AS Q1;
```

I get this error:

> 'Q1.E_ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I get the result only when I keep `MAX(total) AS max_t` in the `SELECT` part but I also want to have the columns `E_ID` and `E_Name`.

Comment: Why not use `TOP`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - just sort by the `Total` column in a descending fashion, and take the first row in the result:

```
SELECT TOP (1)
    Q1.E_ID, Q1.E_Name, Q1.Total
FROM 
    (SELECT  
         E_ID, E_Name, ISNULL(T1, 0) + ISNULL(T2, 0) AS Total
     FROM    
         table1) AS Q1
ORDER BY
    Q1.Total DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without subqueries, by ordering purposefully your data:

```
SELECT TOP 1
       E_Name
FROM tab
ORDER BY COALESCE(T1,0)+COALESCE(T2,0) DESC
```

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=0cca8f7ca28dc45dd1ece505f9176bdc).

Comment: Thanks! It also works. Is there a way to compare both queries regarding the complexity/running time?

Comment: Every time you use subqueries/joins you're adding a layer of complexity, as long as these two operations are the most expensive ones in sql (they're essentially the same join operation dressed with two different clothes). @complog

Comment: I see! Thank you. Btw, you need to add "DESC" for the answer (warning just in case someone else want to have the solution)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the query:

```
SELECT top 1 E_ID, E_Name, (T1+T2) as Total 
FROM Table1 
GROUP BY E_ID,E_Name 
ORDER BY Total desc
```

[image]

Comment: It would again give an error with the same reason as mine: "Table1.T1" and "Table1.T2" are invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Answer (score 0):

SELECT

TOP (1) , E_ID, E_Name, ISNULL(T1, 0) + ISNULL(T2,0) AS Total

FROM
table1

ORDER BY
Total DESC;

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna see all the records you just need to apply the GROUP BY clause.

```
SELECT 
    E_ID
  , E_Name
  , MAX(total) AS max_t
FROM 
    (SELECT  
         E_ID
       , E_Name
       , ISNULL(T1, 0) + ISNULL(T2, 0) AS total
     FROM    
         table1
    ) AS Q1
GROUP BY
    E_ID
  , E_Name;
```

If you want to see only the MAX value in the dataset you just need to apply the TOP 1 (for one record in the result), then sum the T1 and T2 as total and
then apply the ORDER BY DESC;

```
SELECT TOP 1
    E_ID
  , E_Name
  , (T1 + T2) AS total
FROM 
    table1
ORDER BY
    total DESC
```